# UI TableView not returning data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a table view, where the cell is clicked on, and it segues into another tableview. The first tableview works and loads the appropriate data. the second does not display the data. Here is my code:

```
  let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.whereKey("Chemistry", equalTo: true)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (caption: [AnyObject]?, erreur: NSError?) -> Void in
        if erreur == nil {
            // on a réussi
            for caption in caption! {
                self.chemistryListe.append(caption["username"] as! String)
            }

            println("we are here")
            println(self.chemistryListe)

        }
        else {
            // quelque chose s'est passé
        }
    }
```

And here are my cellforRowatIndexPath and numberOfRowsinSection methods:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.chemistryListe.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchResult") as! CompanyTableViewCell

    println(self.chemistryListe)
    cell.nameLabel.text = chemistryListe[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}
```

if I change this line:

```
    cell.nameLabel.text = chemistryListe[indexPath.row]
```

to this:

```
   cell.nameLabel.text = "testcell"
```

then everything works, and it correctly displays the text "testcell". So obviously it is not reading that there is anything in the chemistryListe array. But I set a breakpoint in the middle of my query, and saw that the query was correctly fetching the data that should be in the array, and was putting it into the array. But just the tableview cell isn't reading it. Any idea what could be wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

I just needed to add

```
   self.tableView.reloadData()
```

to the end of the query method.

thanks to all for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first if you have data into the array. Then you if the array contains string change this line to :

```
 cell.nameLabel.text = chemistryListe[indexPath.row] as! String
```

Comment: I tried that, the compiler corrected it to "as" but it still did not work

Comment: did you make sure you have data into the array and try to replace **as!** with **as?**

Comment: yes, I set a println(self.chemistryListe) after the for loop, set a breakpoint, and looked at the log in the console, and it did print the 2 elements in the array that should be there. Just when the compiler reads it at cellForRowatindexPath, it doesnt see any data. I've tried as, as!, and as?, and none of those work.

but in the for loop I am appending the element "as! String" so I don't think the type should be a problem

Comment: you know what create assign  to ** var text = chemistryListe[indexPath.row] as! String** then do **cell.nameLabel.text = text**

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cell.nameLabel.text = chemistryListe[indexPath.row]
```

to

```
cell.nameLabel.text = "\(chemistryListe[indexPath.row])"
```

Comment: still doesn't work. Im wondering if it maybe has something to do with the fact that the view controller before it also contains a tableview. The way I currently have it set up, is there is one cell in tableView #1, and then i crtl+clicked and dragged to make clicking on that cell transition to tableView#2, which is where I am having this problem with the array not showing up. could it be my method of transitioning from one tableView to the next is wrong?

Comment: Are you passing the array to the second view controller?

Comment: No, the contents for the cell in the first viewcontroller/table view are set manually by putting them in an array, meaning I have set the initial contents of the array at the top of the viewController. whereas in tableView #2, the array is empty to start with, then populated with data via retrieving it from parse. I can confirm that the data is being retrieved from parse because the println(self.chemistryListe) after the for loop does print the correct array.